# TensorFlow-GPU causes python crash

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've some trouble with tensorflow-gpu 1.6.0.

I'm doing the final assignment of "bayesan methods in machine learning" class on coursera.

https://www.coursera.org/learn/bayesian-methods-in-machine-learning

When I run the code on GPU with tensorflow-gpu (`pip install tensorflow-gpu`), python crashes, but if I run the same code on CPU with the standard tensorflow (`pip isntall tensorflow`), the code runs fast without errors or crashes. Obviously I unistalled the gpu version before I installed the standard version and vice versa.

About the python crash, the debugger shows this message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDAB4DB79E (ucrtbase.dll) in python.exe
```

**This is the starter code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
import tensorflow as tf
import GPy
import GPyOpt
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, InputLayer, concatenate, Activation, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Deconv2D
from keras.losses import MSE
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras import backend as K
from keras import metrics
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
import utils
import os
%matplotlib inline

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
K.set_session(sess)

latent_size = 8

vae, encoder, decoder = utils.create_vae(batch_size=128, latent=latent_size)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
vae.load_weights('CelebA_VAE_small_8.h5')

K.set_learning_phase(False)

latent_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, latent_size))
decode = decoder(latent_placeholder)
```

**This code causes python crash when is executed on GPU but NOT on CPU:**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5, 5, i+1)
    image = sess.run(decode, feed_dict={latent_placeholder: np.random.normal([0]*latent_size,[1]*latent_size)[:, np.newaxis].T})[0]### YOUR CODE HERE
    plt.imshow(np.clip(image, 0, 1))
    plt.axis('off')
```

**Additional Information:**

- python version 3.6.4
- tensorflow 1.6.0
- tensorflow-gpu 1.6.0
- cuDNN 7.1.1 for CUDA 9.0
- CUDA 9.0 with patch 1 and 2
- GPU 1080ti with driver 391.01

**You can find the python notebook and the weights on wetransfer:**
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/59b9011823d38c204b5ef5a2b58f5e8e20180311201808/32c900

Comment: Probably out of memory error. You should reduce batch size drastically when training on GPU.

Comment: @JahKnows I tried different batch sizes (64-32-16-8-4) with tensorflow-gpu 1.6.0 and 1.5.0 and the issue persists.

Comment: @JahKnows I found the issue. cuDNN 7.1.1 doesn't work yet with tensorflow-gpu. I downgraded cuDNN to 7.0.5 and now the code works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. cuDNN 7.1.1 doesn't work yet with tensorflow-gpu. I downgraded cuDNN to 7.0.5 and now the code works as expected.

If you have a issue like me, you have to downgrade cuDNN!